# fill antd form fields with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I got simple blog (react/redux) (only frontend part). With user registration and articles. And stuck when tryed to fill fields of article editor form.

In "ArticleEditor" component. When I try edit article I got all values in props, and can see it in console log

```
console.log('title:', this.props.title); // title
```

but how to add it to form fields? In form fields values i got -

```
value={this.props.title}
```

but fields its empty. Should i need to somehow update this form? Is't it update when it recieve props?

Plz help if you have good knowledge in React/Redux.

here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-chatterjee-e82j6

Comment: There is no instance of value={this.props.title} in your code - https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-chatterjee-e82j6?file=/src/components/Articles/ArticleEditor.js

Comment: ty. not sure what you talking about. line 123 - ```value={title}``` that title destractured from props - line 98 ```const {title, description, body, tagInput, errors} = this.props;```

Comment: ok so line 123 the reason you don't have a value is because the prop doesn't exist with a value. Thats where you need to look

Comment: that value exist, you can see it in console log. form not update fields and i dont know why. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to your problem is two fold.

1. Replace use of `value` with [`initialValues`](https://ant.design/components/form/#API) for the form
2. Do not show form until values are loaded from the server. When re-rendering happens after state change, original form components are not stored and they are still holding onto first value bound.

```
import React from "react";
import ErrorsList from "../ErrorsList/ErrorsList";
import userService from "../../services/userService";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { push } from "react-router-redux";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";

import { ADD_TAG, REMOVE_TAG } from "../../actionTypes";

import { store } from "../../store";
import actionCreators from "../../actionCreators";
import article from "../../reducers/article";

const formItemLayout = {
  labelCol: { span: 24 },
  wrapperCol: { span: 24 }
};

const formSingleItemLayout = {
  wrapperCol: { span: 24, offset: 0 }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ...state.editor
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onLoad: (payload) => dispatch(actionCreators.doEditorLoaded(payload)),
  onUnload: () => dispatch(actionCreators.doEditorUnloaded()),
  onUpdateField: (key, value) =>
    dispatch(actionCreators.doUpdateFieldEditor(key, value)),
  onSubmit: (payload, slug) => {
    dispatch(actionCreators.doArticleSubmitted(payload));
    store.dispatch(push(`/`)); //article/${slug}
  },
  onRedirect: () => dispatch(actionCreators.doRedirect())
});

class ArticleEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.id = this.props.match.params.id;
    const updateFieldEvent = (key) => (e) =>
      this.props.onUpdateField(key, e.target.value);
    this.changeTitle = updateFieldEvent("title");
    this.changeDescription = updateFieldEvent("description");
    this.changeBody = updateFieldEvent("body");
    this.changeTagInput = updateFieldEvent("tagInput");
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.submitForm = () => {
      const article = {
        title: this.props.title,
        description: this.props.description,
        body: this.props.body,
        tagList: this.props.tagInput.split(",")
      };

      const slug = { slug: this.props.articleSlug };
      const promise = this.props.articleSlug
        ? userService.articles.update(Object.assign(article, slug))
        : userService.articles.create(article);

      this.props.onSubmit(promise, this.props.articleSlug);
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log("id", prevProps.match.params.id);
    if (prevProps.match.params.id !== prevProps.match.params.id) {
      if (prevProps.match.params.id) {
        this.props.onUnload();
        return this.props.onLoad(
          userService.articles.get(this.props.match.params.id)
        );
      }
      this.props.onLoad(null);
    }
    this.isLoading = false;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.id) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      return this.props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(this.id));
    }
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.props.onLoad(null);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onUnload();
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.props;
    const initialValues = {
      title: this.props?.title,
      body: this.props?.body,
      description: this.props?.description,
      tags: this.props?.tagList
    };

    return this.isLoading ? (
      "loading..."
    ) : (
      <div className="editor-page">
        <div className="container page">
          <div className="">
            <div className="">
              <ErrorsList errors={errors}></ErrorsList>
              <Form
                {...formItemLayout}
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onFinish={this.submitForm}
              >
                <Form.Item
                  label="Title"
                  name="title"
                  placeholder="Article Title"
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: "Please input article title"
                    }
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input onChange={this.changeTitle} />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                  label="Description"
                  name="description"
                  placeholder="Short description"
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: "Please input article description"
                    }
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input onChange={this.changeDescription} />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                  name="body"
                  label="Article Text"
                  placeholder="article text"
                >
                  <Input.TextArea onChange={this.changeBody} />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name="tags" label="Tags" placeholder="Enter tags">
                  <Input onChange={this.changeTagInput} />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item {...formSingleItemLayout}>
                  <Button
                    className="editor-form__btn"
                    type="primary"
                    htmlType="submit"
                    disabled={this.props.inProgress}
                  >
                    Submit Article
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticleEditor);
```

take a look at [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-flower-4oxkz).

Comment: thx alot. I tried it. now i got undefined id when create new article. why the code different in list above and at codesandbox? I see ```const initialValues = { ...this.props };
``` in code here, but not in code at codesandbox. can you explain plz in few words what you did?

Comment: have no idea what happend. When i press edit - form loaded with blank fields, and then when i edit code - seems codesandbox update the page, and fill form fields.

Comment: @WillBlack not sure why sandbox was different for you I forked sandbox and fixed issue related to new article. Take a look at updated answer.

Comment: thats strange :/ when i copy-paste code  from "ArticleEditor" component to project I got warning "Warning: [antd: Form.Item] `defaultValue` will not work on controlled Field. You should use `initialValues` of Form instead." and empty form. :( but in codesandbox its seems worked.

Comment: @WillBlack are you sure you are suing same version of antd on your project and codesandbox? Compare package.json file and verify.

Comment: yes - its the same: project -"antd": "^4.6.5",  codesandbox - "antd": "^4.6.5" :(

Comment: @WillBlack I think I am seeing the same issue after updating codesandbox, I used `initialValues` now and updated answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-flower-4oxkz

Comment: I think i missing something important. :( copy "ArticleEditor" file.. and... got blank form. :((((  Thats what i got now - https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-leaf-mlydm  did you change come other files?

Comment: @WillBlack your codesandbox has different code than one you originally shared. Also if you do `console.log` of props in your component, its not working either which is why article data is not loaded so it has something to do with your changes.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked that you are using v4 not v3

you can use fields props in Form Component

```
<Form
   {...formItemLayout}
   onFinish={this.submitForm}
   fields={[
     {
       name: ['title'],
       value: title,
     },
   ]}
>
```

Comment: Every answer on the web says use `initialValues` except your answer. It's the `fields` that works for implementing update feature. Life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Add `defalutValue` prop in Input with value eg:

`<Input.TextArea value={body} defaultValue={body} onChange={this.changeBody} />`

Comment: ty. I tryed this defaultValue={title} fields still blank when form loaded. – Will Black 35 secs ago